# What is project reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

there is a possibility to add an existing project as a "reference" to a solution in VS(talking about C++ now). As far as I understand it means that all the project files will be added to a solution and I can modify any properties and source code, and it will affect the original solution to which this project belongs. Do I have a correct understanding of it? Or is it something else?
I don't really get why we need it, if I need another project I can use it as a lib or DLL file, this reference thing seems to make things more complicated - if I do any changes to project properties I need to think how it will affect building another solution this project belongs to.

Comment: I once had to work with a project which used references and it was a nightmare. I would avoid it as I don't see any benefits, but lots of problems with it. Just my opinion.

Comment: @Devolus it's not my choice :( Currently I'm concerning do I understand correctly what happened - that I have one project with same files that are built with same properties within two different solution. And looking for somebody who can confirm that my understanding is correct, or tells me where I'm wrong and how it works in reality.

Comment: Used to make the build order work.  A referenced project is is built before the project referring to it.  eg if you need to use a static library project from the main app project you create a reference to the static library project so it gets built before the main project.  If you didn't do this the main project could link with the old static library.

Comment: @RichardCritten, you can also configure this with the build dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual C++ "project-to-project" references within a solution really does two things:

- If the referenced project is a static or DLL library, it's implicitly included in your referencing project's link statement.
- The referenced project is considered a build-dependency for the referencing project so it will be built first.

That's pretty much it. If you want to include headers in the referenced project, you need to add it your `AdditionalIncludes` property for the referencing project.

For a DLL project, you can set a property on it to get it's DLL copied to your referencing project's build directory.

See [Visual C++ Team Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/flexible-project-to-project-references/) which was back in VS 2010 when it was first introduced.

> There's a different model of code sharing called [Shared Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects) where the shared code is built in each referencing project--i.e. there's no shared binaries.

Comment: And what benefits it gives comparing to using static libs?

Comment: It is simply a way to organize your static or dynamic libs in a larger solution.